# While updating software my computer crashed (I think overheated). Now, I can't login, it keeps taking me back to login page

Tags: login, login-screen, overheating

Now, when I attempt to login it accepts my Ubuntu login password, but then flashes a strange distorted black screen with seemingly random characters (quickly) and takes me back to the login screen.

I can press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to the terminal and I can login through the terminal and see my files.

Any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `sudo apt upgrade` from the text console? This would start a second attempt to do the same software upgrade. It should remember which packages weren't installed completely and either re-do them or throw some helpful errors.

Comment: No haven't, but I will try that (I'm not sure why I didn't think of that myself, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Log into the terminal (any of `ctrl+alt+F1` thru F6). Then run:

`sudo apt update;
sudo apt upgrade;`

If that complains, try:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Then run the `apt` commands again.

That should get you going as normal.

If that still doesn't work, you might need to reconfigure X:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`